# Need To change the format output of a hashtable into file

Tags: powershell, format, hashtable

I want to print a hashtable result into a file but in a different format

```
$hashTMP = @{
    'vivid.img' = '$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Samples\Inbound\OCR - DICOM\Vivid';
    'Vivid.xml' = '$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Defaults\OCR';
    'Zonare.xml' = '$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Defaults\OCR';
}

$hashTMP.GetEnumerator() | sort key
```

The desired output format looks like this:

```
vivid.img,$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Samples\Inbound\OCR - DICOM\Vivid;
Vivid.xml,$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Defaults\OCR;
Zonare.xml,$ProgramFiles\Medcon\ApplicationServer\ISFiles\Defaults\OCR;
```

Comment: $hashTMP.GetEnumerator() |sort key| % { "$($_.Key),$($_.Value)" }

Comment: `$hashTMP.GetEnumerator()|sort key|%{$_.key,$_.value -join ','}` or `$hashTMP.GetEnumerator()|sort key|%{"{0},{1}" -f $_.Key,$_.Value}` or `$hashTMP.GetEnumerator()|sort key|%{$_.key+','+$_.value}`